# C + + Builder 10.4.1 compiler running error in XP

Tags: c++builder-10.4-sydney

[image]

Link with Dynamic RTL=true

Compiler running under XP prompt error

> Unable to locate the program input point acquiresrwlockshared on the dynamic link library kernel32.dll.

Answer (score 1):

`AcquireSRWLockShared()` was introduced in Windows Vista.  Clearly something in your project is static-linking to that function, so the error message makes sense when running your code on XP.  Note also that you enabled the Dynamic RTL, but you did not also enable the Delphi Runtime Library, too.  Typically, most C++Builder users *disable* these options to produce standalone executables, but you seem to want to *enable* them instead to utilize runtime BPLs (which will still fail to load on XP btw, even if your main EXE could run).

XP is no longer a supported platform.  You can't run the IDE itself on XP, nor can you run programs compiled with 10.4 on XP.  The IDE itself requires Windows 10 or later.  Compiled programs require Windows 7 SP1 or later.  See [Operating System Requirements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Installation_Notes#Operating_System_Requirements) in 10.4's documentation.

The last version to *officially* support compiled programs running on XP was XE2.  Support for XP was dropped in XE3.

Comment: C + + Builder 10.3.3 can run normally on XP,There is no way to deal with this problem. I can only upgrade the project back to c++builder10.3.3

Comment: @lctong “*C + + Builder 10.3.3 can run normally on XP*” - not officially. And it is perfectly reasonable for the IDE and RTL to evolve and utilize new APIs that don’t exist on outdated platforms.

Comment: I see. Thank you